# How can I make an AngularJs directive work at a specific screen size

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive that adds and removes a class to a header section when I scroll the page, a hide/show header. I would like to have this directive work only on a screen size less than 600px. Any help would be appreciated.

### My Angular Directive

```js
.directive('scrollClass', function ($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        var current;
        current = $window.pageYOffset;
        angular.element($window).on('scroll', function () {
            var ref;
            if ($window.innerHeight + $window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                scope.scrolled = false;
            } else {
                scope.scrolled = (ref = this.pageYOffset > current) != null ? ref : { 'true': false };
            }
            current = this.pageYOffset;
            return scope.$apply();
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

### My HTML Element

```html
<header class='top-menu' ng-class='{ "scrolled" : scrolled }' scroll-class=''>
```

Comment: simple addition of an `if()` clause that checks window width is all that is needed

Comment: All the css libraries have this capability. Bootstrap, foundation, angular-material. If you use any one of those it should be trivial to manage visibility wrt screen size

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I just realized that all I had to do was wrap the "scrolled" class in a media query. I'm new to Angular and scripting in general and am not sure if this approach goes against Angular best practices, but it's worked well.